# How to pass my createReadStream of an image file into a HTTP Post Request Body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api

I'm writing a test that ensures my API does not allow files >10MB. And I need to pass an image into this API as a Post Request.

I believe I've figured out how I read the data from my image
(If I log out assetSteam.on then I can see bytesRead is the correct size of my file =  bytesRead: 16337697)

```
export async function uploadPhoto(filePath: string): Promise<any> {
  const assetStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
  assetStream.on('data', function (rawImageData) {
    return myPhoto.uploadImage(JSON.stringify(rawImageData));
  });
}
```

The argument passed into myPhoto.uploadImage is the body for the HTTP request.

I'm unsure as to how I pass this data to be read correctly as an image into my Post request body

Comment: you have to collect data until it's complete, then you have your image data ready for consumption by another routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going for a much simpler solution

```
  const imageData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, { encoding: 'base64' });
```

Then passed stringified `imageData` into the body of my request.

Worked a treat.